# Возможно ли документировать миксины / функции в SASS?

Tags: sass, gulp-sass

Здравсвуйте.

Не так давно стал писать на sass и не могу понять подобного функционала нет или я его нагуглить не могу :).

Возможно ли описывать создаваемые миксины или функции (какие переменные принимает), надподобие phpdoc.

И в дальнейшем при вызове миксина смотреть эту инфу?

Comment: Видимо плохо [гуглили](https://sass-guidelin.es/ru/#section-49) - `/// @param {Length} $width
/// @param {Length} $height`

Comment: именно это я и находил, но к сожалению не работает и sassdoc ставил, но это не совсем то. пример приведенный в топике (phpdoc) работает иначе.